# Setting values for Get and Post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, model, http-post

I am developing an MVC C# application.

Here is my code:

```
     //
    // GET: /Comment/Create
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Create(int bookid = 0)
    {
        var comment = new Comment();
        comment.Book = _bookService.GetBookFromBookId(bookid);
        comment.Owner = _userService.GetLoggedInUser();
        return View(comment);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Comment/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Comment comment)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Comments.Add(comment);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index","Book",null);
        }

        return View(comment);
    }
```

In the Get Create ActionResult, the Book and Owner values are set for a Comment object, however, in the HttpPost Create ActionResult the values are not in the object.

How can I get this code working correctly?

**UPDATE**

Here is my View code:

```
@model LearningTestMVCApplication.Models.Comment

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Comment</legend>
    <p>
        Book Name: @Html.DisplayFor(model =>  model.Book.Name)
    </p>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DisplayText)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DisplayText)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DisplayText)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

I have debugged the View, and the object properties are there...

Comment: What does your view look like? have you tried debugging to see if the comment object has the expected values?

Comment: Can you post the contents of your View? Without seeing your View, I would first look at the 'name' property of your inputs there and make sure that they match the property names of your Comment model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your POST action, the only part of the object that exists is that data that was actually represented in form by a field. If you didn't provide fields (hidden or otherwise) for the book and user, then they won't be in your post and your model there will not have those objects.

However, in a situation like this, you wouldn't want to do that anyways. You're not allowing them to change that information; you're merely creating associations. So what you should have is:

```
// GET: /Comment/Create
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Create(int bookid)
{
    var comment = new Comment();
    return View(comment);
}

//
// POST: /Comment/Create

[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(int bookid, Comment comment)
{
    comment.Book = _bookService.GetBookFromBookId(bookid);
    comment.Owner = _userService.GetLoggedInUser();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Comments.Add(comment);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index","Book",null);
    }

    return View(comment);
}
```

See the difference? Your POST action should also take the book id, and it'll use that to look up the right book to save with the rest of the object data. The GET action now only takes the book id to identity the URL for posting to. (You can now just do `@Html.BeginForm()` without having to pass in any route parameters to have it just postback to the same URL.) You *might* still want to look up the book in the GET action, but this would only be for display purposes in the view; it would not actually affect the data sent back to the POST action.

The user information should *always* be controlled by the POST action. You should never, ever, ever post something like an owner for a thing, as any post values can be manipulated, allowing a malicious user to associate the object with whatever they like.